# List of all fonts installed on google Doc/Slide using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, font-family, google-slides

I want to get the list/array of all fonts installed on Google Docs or Google Slides. Specifically, I have a Google Slides file and want to get the list of all Fonts. I am not talking about the Fonts used inside the Slides Text but all fonts are available to choose from as we have those in the dropdown section.

I tried and found [Enum FontFamily](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/font-family) in the documentation but the documentation says that now this is Deprecated. However, I tried the enum and retrieved the value and I got these:

> [function toString() { [native code] }, function toString() { [native code] }, function toString() { [native code] }, function ordinal() { [native code] }, function compareTo() { [native code] }, Amaranth, Arial, Arial Black, Arial Narrow, Arvo, Calibri, Cambria, Comic Sans MS, Consolas, Corsiva, Courier New, Dancing Script, Droid Sans, Droid Serif, Garamond, Georgia, Gloria Hallelujah, Great Vibes, Lobster, Merriweather, pacifico, Philosopher, Poiret One, Quattrocento, Roboto, Shadows into Light, Syncopate, Tahoma, Times New Roman, Trebuchet MS, Ubuntu, Verdana]

This does contain the fonts but those are just a few.

The documentation says that:

> The methods getFontFamily() and setFontFamily(String) now use string names for fonts instead of this enum

The functions `getFontFamily()` and `setFontFamily(String)` needs the name of the FontFamily as a string but I am interested to get the list of all available Fonts to choose from.

Specifically, I want this for Google Slides.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to get this information via Apps Scripts.

However if you’d like to file a new Feature Request, you can use [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918).